# X Server triggered (minval > maxval)

Tags: linux, qt, debian, x11, xorg

I have touch-devices with Debian (jessie) on it.

It runs a qt/qml-program and a X.Org X Server with no Problems, but on some devices the touch-input doesn’t work properply (immediately after boot up or after some time).
It recognizes a touch (programm wakes up from "SleepMode"), but a click on for e.g. buttons doesn't work.

When I connect to the x11vnc Server on the device I can work on it normal.

When this happens the X Server prints the following Error:

```
(EE) BUG: triggered 'if (minval > maxval && mode == 1)'
(EE) BUG: ../../Xi/exevents.c:2087 in InitValuatorAxisStruct()
(EE)
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE)
```

What causes this error and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Update the Touchscreen needs some additonal parameter.

The solution for me was to update the *.dtb file.